# Thomas algorithm python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner at Python. I have the following code that doesn't return anything.

Does any one have an answer as to why? When I execute the code, literally nothing happens.

## Finding the size of the matrix and determine n

```
def thomas(a,b,c,d):

    a= [1,3,1.5,4.5,4.5]
    b= [-6,-4.5,-7.5,-7.5,-4.5] 
    c= [3,3,3,3,3]
    d= [0,0,100,0,0]

    n = len(b)
    #print n # Used for debugging
    # Test the size of a and c
    if len(a) != n-1:
        print ('Wrong index size for a.\n A should have an index of'), n-1, '\n 
    Your a has ', len(a)
    exit()
    if len(c) != n-1:
        print ('Wrong index size for c.\n C should have an index of'), n-1, '\n 
    Your c has', len(c)
    exit()

# Converting to float and appending 0.0 to c
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        a[i] = float(a[i])
    for i in range(0,len(b)):
        b[i] = float(b[i])
    for i in range(0,len(c)):
        c[i] = float(c[i])
    for i in range(0,len(d)):
        d[i] = float(d[i])
c.append(0.0) # Hack to make the function to work

# Calculate p and q
    p = []; q= [] 
    p.append(c[0]/b[0]); q.append(d[0]/b[0])
    for j in range(1,n):
        pj = c[j]/(b[j] - a[j-1]* p[j-1])
        qj = (d[j] - a[j-1]*q[j-1])/(b[j] - a[j-1]* p[j-1])
        p.append(pj); q.append(qj)
#print p,q # Used for debugging the code!

# Back sub
    x = []; x.append(q[n-1])
    for j in range(n-2,-1,-1):
        xj = q[j] - p[j]*x[0] # Value holder
        x.insert(0,xj) # Building the list backwards

# Return the value
    return x
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Perhaps all you need is a one-line main program that calls this, but we need to be sure.

Comment: your `exit` call are outside the `if` and are always executed

Comment: Thx for the response, but even without the `exit` still nothing happens....

Comment: The code you posted merely defines a function.  There's no call to make it compute or print anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentations are screwy.

On lines 13 and 17, indent the `exit` statement so that its only called when the conditional (if statement) is satisfied:

```
  if len(a) != n-1:
      print ('Wrong index size for a.\n A should have an index of')
      exit()
  if len(c) != n-1:
      print ('Wrong index size for c.\n C should have an index of')
      exit()
```

Likewise, `c.append(0.0)` is outdented a tab too far. Indent this line as well.

Remember that, unlike most other languages, Python bases its executional structure on spacing. For something like an if statement, everything indented under that statement is considered the same as `if (something) {  }`.

```
if (something):
      do this
      and this
but this will happen regardless
```